# Java Script combine strings/arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, split

I need to combine `string1` and `string2` like first result.
After that, I only want the unique information, without "color type information" like the second result.

```
string1 = "Green | Green | Red | Orange | Blue | Cut | Yellow | Yellow"

string2 = "Color | Color | Color | Color | Color | Technical | Color | Color"
```

**First result:** string3 = Green Color | Green Color | Red Color | Orange Color | Blue Color | Cut Technical | Yellow Color | Yellow Color

**Second result:** string4 = Green | Red | Orange | Blue | Cut | Yellow

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960473/get-all-unique-values-in-a-javascript-array-remove-duplicates

Comment: Other one is just a simple loop and combine the two arrays. map() will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
string1 = "Green | Green | Red | Orange | Blue | Cut | Yellow | Yellow"

split_text = string1.split("|")
Result = Array.from(new Set(split_text.map(x => x.trim()))).join('|')
//'Green|Red|Orange|Blue|Cut|Yellow'
```

Comment: You forgot to split before trimming.

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this

```js
const string1 = 'Green | Green | Red | Orange | Blue | Cut | Yellow | Yellow'
const string2 = 'Color | Color | Color | Color | Color | Technical | Color | Color'

const [arr1, arr2] = [string1, string2].map(s => s.split(' | '))


const string3 = arr1.map((s, i) => `${s} ${arr2[i]}`).join(' | ')
const string4 = [...new Set(arr1)].join(' | ')
console.log({string3, string4})
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const string1 = 'Green | Green | Red | Orange | Blue | Cut | Yellow | Yellow'
const string2 = 'Color | Color | Color | Color | Color | Technical | Color | Color'

const combine = (str1, str2, div = ' | ') => {
  str1 = str1.split(div)
  str2 = str2.split(div)
  
  return str1.map((word, i) => `${word} ${str2[i]}`).join(div)
}

const unique = str1 => [...new Set(str1.split(' | '))].join(' | ')

const firstResult = `Green Color | Green Color | Red Color | Orange Color | Blue Color | Cut Technical | Yellow Color | Yellow Color`
const secondResult = 'Green | Red | Orange | Blue | Cut | Yellow'

console.log(firstResult === combine(string1, string2))
console.log(secondResult === unique(string1))
```

Answer (score 0):

If string1 and string2 information length varies

```js
var string1 = "Green | Green | Red | Orange | Blue | Cut | Yellow | Yellow";

var string2 = "Color | Color | Color | Color | Color | Technical | Color | Color";

var firstlength=string1.split("|").length;
var secondlength=string2.split("|").length;
var maxilength=firstlength;
if(secondlength>firstlength)
  maxilength=secondlength;
 
 var string1split=string1.split("|");
 var string2split=string2.split("|");
 
 var concatstr="";
 for(var i=0;i<maxilength;i++){
 if(string1split.length>i){
   concatstr+=string1split[i];
 }
 if(string2split.length>i){
   concatstr+=string2split[i];
 }
 if(i<maxilength-1){
   concatstr+="|";
 }
}
 
console.log(concatstr);
 
function onlyUnique(value, index, self) {
  return self.indexOf(value) === index;
}
for(var i=0;i<string1split.length;i++){
string1split[i]=string1split[i].trim();
}
var uniquecolors=string1split.filter(onlyUnique);
var uniquecolorsstring=uniquecolors.join(" | ");
console.log(uniquecolorsstring);
```

Comment: This is very helpful, i can use it for my case!